# Is there any project layout that satisfies mavens release plugin?

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-release-plugin

I have a multi-module project and can't perform a release.

I tried these layouts:

```
svnroot/trunk/parent
              /module1
              /module2
```

and

```
svnroot/parent/trunk
svnroot/module1/trunk
svnroot/module2/trunk
```

After reading

- http://ericmiles.wordpress.com/tag/flat-structure/ and
- http://ericmiles.wordpress.com/tag/release-plugin/

I hoped that the 1st layout would work, but in both cases maven terminates with this error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).

Project ID: unknown

 Reason: Could not find the model file 'C:\myworkspace\parent\target\module1'. for project unknown
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It seems that some work is already done when this error occurs, all version numbers are updated in the poms.

I recgonized that the parent module was checkout under parent\target\checkout and it seems that the plugin expects the modules checked out under target.

- Did I miss an important setting ?
- Could anyone describe how he got the mvn release to work?

The parent.pom has the following settings

```
    <groupId>company.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

     <modules>
        <module>../module1</module>
        <module>../module2</module>
    </modules> 

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:svn:file:///SVNROOT/trunk/parent</connection>
        <url>file:///SVNROOT/trunk/parent</url>
    </scm>

     <dependency>
            <groupId>company.project</groupId>
            <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
     </dependency>
```

A modules pom looks like this

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>company.project</groupId>
    <version>1.0.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<name>module1</name>
<artifactId>module1</artifactId>

<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:file:///SVNROOT/trunk/module1</connection>
    <url>file:///SVNROOT/trunk/module1</url>
</scm>
```

The release is invoked by

```
mvn -e -DcommitByProject=true -DautoVersionSubmodules=true  -Dresume=false release:prepare  release:perform
```

Maven version is 2.2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My structure is

```
/svnroot/trunk/parent
/svnroot/trunk/parent/module1
/svnroot/trunk/parent/module2
```

etc. and I haven't had any trouble with building or using the release plugin. I'm currently on 3.0.3, but I *think* it worked on 2.2.x. In any case, it doesn't match either of the structures you list in your question and might be worth a try.

Comment: @jtahlborn do you have a link to further documentation?

Answer (score -2):

Edit: As I noted below, this was an issue with an Eclipse plugin - sorry for the confusion

If I am not mistaken, starting in Maven 2.2 multi module project setups stopped being supported.  We had a product move up to Maven 2.2 for other reasons, and found that a previous problem-free multi module project stopped building correctly.

Comment: no, maven has not stopped supporting multi-module projects.  that would exclude using maven for most projects of medium size and up.

Comment: Sorry, there was an assumption on my behalf there - our issue was with a specific maven plugin for eclipse that didn't like the change.  Please disregard my answer.